# How to change the UITextfield cursor color in iOS6

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to change an `UITextField` cursor color on iOS6.

```
textField.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

is working fine in iOS7 but it not on iOS6.

Any help will be appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API to change the cursor colour in iOS 6. This an iOS 7+ feature only.

If you want to do this you'll have to subclass `UITextField` - and that's a lot of work!